# Maven jars going to wrong folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I am working in a project which was started 10 years ago. Right now everything here is a mess. I am facing a problem with maven.

The repository structure of maven is something like this:

```
.m2/repository/com/company/project/
```

inside project folder there are folder for different version. like

```
15.10.4
15.10.5
15.10.6
15.10.7
```

Our project is divided into two modules. When we build First modules jars are installed in maven repository and then we add this repository in class path and use them in Second module.

Now the problem is when I am building using 
mvn clean install
in target folder I am getting project-name-15.10.8.jar. Problem is these jars should go in folder 15.10.8 but there is no folder of that name there. Even if I create a folder of name 15.10.8 in repository no jars are getting installed there. I checked in pom.xml and profile.xml everywhere version mentioned is 15.10.8 only. Where should I look for proper configuration so that I can find out what is wrong?

**Solution:**

I found the solution. Actually in $MAVEN_HOME/settings.xml local repo was configure to C:/MAVEN_REPO/
I don't know how but it was changed to default as in C:/user/username/....
I changed it back to C:/MAVEN_REPO and now jars are being build in proper directory.

Also while fiddling with maven configuration files I found that this build directory name is controlled by profile.xml.

Right now I am looking into maven's explanation on profiles.

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: execute mvn clean install -DskipTests -X and paste output here

Comment: Snippet of your pon would help

Comment: Very sorry, but code base in on client machine. I cannot post configuration files of output here. :(

Comment: Which version of Maven do you use? profile.xml was only valid in Maven 2.2.1 apart from that it was called `profiles.xml`. And you should be aware of [EoL of Maven 2.X](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html)

Comment: Maven version is 2.2.1

Comment: POM files will be really helpfull otherwise it's more or less impossible to see what's going wrong.

Comment: This sounds like Maven is being slightly misused.  Consider reworking the pom so the artifact is just installed in the same way as any other artifact, and then use the Maven support in your IDE to set up the build path correctly by referring to the artifact in the pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a built file inside the target folder, try to fire the install goal to move it explicitelly inside your local repository with below command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=$PATH_TO_PROJECT_ROOT/target/project-name-15.10.8.jar -DgroupId=com.company.project -DartifactId=project-name -Dversion=15.10.8 -Dpackaging=jar
```

PS: A snippet from your pom.xml file will be really useful tofigure out the problem.